# Expo React Native - Json.map() - Dynamic Data Clickable

Tags: javascript, json, react-native, function, expo

I'm working on an React Native application where I want to display some part of my elements only when I click another element.

I achieved that using `const [showSlide, setShowSlide] = useState(false);` and then using conditionnal show like `{showSlide ? (<View>Element</View>): null}`

It work very good in my static demo but I would like to have the same result using `json.map()` function.

I don't figure how to make an unique reference to the think I want to hide/show in my map function.

I made a demo here to show my dynamic data and the static one as a reference of what I want to do : https://snack.expo.dev/@37creaorganization/json-data---clickable

```js
export default function App() {

  const [showSlide, setShowSlide] = useState(false);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
    {/* STATIC EXAMPLE */}
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {setShowSlide(!showSlide)}}>
      <Text style={styles.paragraph}>
        {dataC.customer[0].name}   
      </Text>
      {showSlide ? (
        <View>
          <Text>{dataC.customer[0].requests[0].title}</Text>
        </View>
      ) : null}
    </TouchableOpacity>
    {/* END OF STATIC EXAMPLE */}
    <View style={{width:"100%", height:5, backgroundColor:"red", marginTop: 10, marginBottom: 10}}></View>
    <Text style={{textAlign: "center"}}>DYNAMIC EXAMPLE</Text>
    {/* DYNAMIC DATA */}
    { dataC.customer.map((customer)=>(
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {setShowSlide(!showSlide)}}>
        <Text style={styles.paragraph}>
          {customer.name}   
        </Text>
          <View>
            <Text>{customer.requests[0].title} </Text>
          </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    ))}
    {/* END OF DYNAMIC DATA*/}
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: Your code should be posted **here**, not on some external site.  You've been on this site for **six years**, certainly you should know that.

Comment: @Pointy I will update it.

Answer (score 0):

Its always best practice to separate component in React

```
const Customer = ({customer, titleVisible=false, toggleVisible})=>{
  const onToggleVisible = ()=>toggleVisible && toggleVisible(customer.name);
  return (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={onToggleVisible}>
        <Text style={styles.paragraph}>
          {customer.name}
        </Text>
        {titleVisible && <View>
          <Text>{customer.requests[0].title} </Text>
        </View>}
      </TouchableOpacity>
  )
}
```

Above component displays customer as per your requirement.

In your `App` component declare

```
const [show, setShow] = useState({});
```

Here we will store boolean agains title name.

Toggle visible function will look like

```
 const toggleVisible = (name)=>{
    if(show[name]){
      setShow({...show, [name]:false}) //Updating it to false as its already visible
    } else {
      setShow({...show, [name]:true}) //Its not visible so let's make it visible
    }
  }
```

You can use above Customer component as below

```
{ dataC.customer.map((customer)=>(
      <Customer customer={customer} titleVisible={show[customer.name]} toggleVisible={toggleVisible}/>
    ))}
```